# PHP Twitter followers - default value if error

Tags: php, twitter

I'm using a PHP snippet to display my volume of Twitter followers:

```
<?php    
$screenName = 'photogenixlincs';
$getData = 'followers_count';
$xml = file_get_contents('http://twitter.com/users/show.xml?screen_name=' . $screenName);
if(preg_match('/' . $getData . '>(.*)</', $xml, $match) !=0)
echo $match[1];
?>
```

We all know that Twitter can be a bit dodgy and sometimes the PHP code displays on the page - which compared to 3 digit Twitter followers is a nightmare. Is there any way to include a failure event to either prevent the PHP being written or just include a default n/a for example if it fails to load correctly for any reason?

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Throw an exception and use try catch.